# NodeJS Class Method Asynchronous return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently writing a class in JavaScript with a login method.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const util = require('util');
const Settings = require('./config');
const config = new Settings();
const http = require('request');

class Client extends EventEmitter {

constructor(username, password) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

get login() {
    return this.login();
}



login() {
    http.post({
      url:     config.host + "v" + config.version + "/method/account.signIn.inc.php",
      body:    "username="+ this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&clientid=" + config.clientid
    }, function(error, response, body){
      return body;
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Client;
```

I am using the request module to make HTTP requests but request is using asynchronous calls and I am always getting `undefined` when calling `console.log(client.login());` from another file. I have seen many solutions targeting asynchronous calls with callbacks, but I cant seem to figure it out with callbacks or promises within a class.

Comment: It being in a `class` doesn't really make a difference. Use the same solutions you found.

Comment: well these doesn't really work out. I cant define a callback parameter in the getter. declaring login(); as a `function` doesnt work either.

Comment: Then don't use a getter. Or use a different method name from the getter. Either way, you won't be able to return the result directly to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this — callbacks, events, promises. Most people tend to like the solutions with promises and this is a good use case for them. With promises you can do something like this:

```
login() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.post({
        url: config.host + "v" + config.version + "/method/account.signIn.inc.php",
        body: "username="+ this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&clientid=" + config.clientid
        }, function(error, response, body){
            if (error) return reject(error)
            resolve(body);
        });
    })
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
let client = new Client(username, password)
client.login()
.then(result => {
   // result available here
})
.catch(err => {
    // an error 
})
```

Having said that, it also looks like you are defining the class as a subclass of `EventEmitter`, which suggests you want to use events. You can also use this to indicate the login with something like:

```
login() {
    http.post({
    url:     config.host + "v" + config.version + "/method/account.signIn.inc.php",
    body:    "username="+ this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&clientid=" + config.clientid
    }, (error, response, body) => {
    this.emit("loggedIn", body)
    });
}
```

Then wait for the event after you call `login()`

```
let client = new Client(username, password)
client.on("loggedin", (returnVal) => console.log("returned", returnVal))
client.login()
```

Of course, you'll want some error checking, and you'll probably want to set a flag on your instance after logging in, so you can just check that after the initial login.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a bunch! Yes, I use emitters and your example is really helpful. How would I go about adding a variable? The API returns an `authToken` which is required to interact with the API anywhere else.

Comment: @JbSel you can pass whatever you want in `this.emit()` and then receive it in the handler - I updated the answer. It emits the `body` variable and receive it as `returnVal`

Comment: This is not the approach I wanted to do, I have in the constructor the variable `this.accessToken = null;`, it's null and after the emit event in `login();` I set the variable `this.accessToken = body.accessToken;` But it is still null when I call it in the other file using `console.log("AccessToken: "+ client.accessToken);`.

Comment: You can set `this.accessToken = body.accessToken` in the http callback in `login()`. But in the other file you won't be able to access it until the async operation has happened. So in the other file you either need to listen for the event, or wait for the promise,  before calling `console.log()`.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a bunch it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I think `login()` should return a promise :

```
login() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.post({
      url: config.host + "v" + config.version + "/method/account.signIn.inc.php",
      body: "username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&clientid=" + config.clientid
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
}
```

and when calling it :

```
client.login().then(result => console.log(result));
```

I'm kinda new to NodeJS and asynchronous programming but I think it's the way for doing this.